# Unable to reach access point

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

I followed [these instructions](http://wifi-setup.blogspot.com/2008/05/dwl-2100ap-installation-guide.html) to setup my Access Point.

My Router is reachable via  Wireless but non of my devices pick up any signal from the Access Point. The name simply doesn't show up.

The Wireless light in the AP blinks correctly and both Router and AP are connected through an Ethernet cable.

The screenshots below show the current settings for both Router (D-Link [DSL-2640T](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=ftp://public.dlink.co.id/ADSL%2520Modem-Router/DSL-2640T/Manual-QIG/DSL-2640T.TF%2520Manual_v02_080701.pdf&ei=gsSfU_WaHcXisASMr4KgCg&usg=AFQjCNEahC0G-qTYRLmFfkeY5zyctIGq-Q&sig2=OShJRtK78FyLutS1meKBSw&bvm=bv.68911936,d.cWc)) and Access Point ([DWL-2100AP](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http://www.dlink.com/-/media/Business_Products/DWL/DWL%25202100AP/Manual/dwl2100ap_manual_EN_USA.pdf&ei=2MOfU6KuHLDnsATM54KIDQ&usg=AFQjCNEl6SPtxKbKbGvtVNlvKzwIE4za0Q&sig2=ECdMRleQss6WJnal6E_8Xg&bvm=bv.68911936,d.cWc)).

[image: D-Link DSL-2640T]
[image: DWL-2100AP]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you can see your router but can't see the AP from wireless device ? Please specify what you ask for.

Comment: Exactly. Access point and router are two different things.

Comment: How are you connecting the two devices to your network? So far you've just shown us that they are both publishing the same wireless network. Are they both wired into the same Ethernet? By the way, why WPA[1]/TKIP instead of modern WPA2/AES-CCMP? Do you really have any ancient (c. 2003) devices around that are capable of WPA but not WPA2?

Comment: Yes they are connected through Ethernet cable. And the Wireless light in the AP blinks.

Comment: Have you tried a different channel on either the AP or the router ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with either the SSID broadcasting, or the channel.

Set the "SSID Broadcasting" to 'Disable', apply the settings and then change it back to "Enable".

Also enable the "Auto Channel Scan". This will tell the router to look for an empty channel to use for WIFI instead. There could be a lot of interference on the default channel 6.

Click apply, and wait for the router to apply the settings. You may need to cycle the power for the changes to work.